# Grails file resources.groovy ignored by Spring Tool Suite

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

Latest version of STS (e.g. 3.7.3) does not support Grails anymore so I'm using STS Gradle projects as workaround in order to run my Grails applications with "Spring Boot App" option. It's working just fine, but I have faced the issue below:

**Issue:**

Somehow all the beans declared under **resources.groovy** file have been ignored when I execute the application via STS running as "Spring Boot App". Notice that running the application via console "run-app" command it works fine.

**Exception:**

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facebookAuthRedirectFilter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redirectFailureHandlerExample' while setting bean property 'authenticationFailureHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'redirectFailureHandlerExample' is defined`

**My resources.groovy file**

```
package spring
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

beans = {
    redirectFailureHandlerFacebook(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        setDefaultFailureUrl('/login/auth')
    }
}
```

**STS:**

Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201602250940
Platform: Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)

**Grails:**

Grails Version: 3.1.1
Groovy Version: 2.4.5
JVM Version: 1.7.0_75

It seems **classpath** issue but I could not find how to resolve this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved by updating Groovy compiler settings. Go to **Window->Preferences->Groovy->Compiler**, see below:

[image]

Doing this **resources.groovy** will be compiled and the beans will be available on run time.